# How can I change int variable to factor in R

Tags: r

I have below dataset. I would like to set the type of variable for

> "$ Decision"

as factor. 
I tried the command: `as.factor(mydataR$Decision)`
But I guess it didn't work because when I do `str(mydataR)` "$ Decision" still shows as a numeric value. I am wondering, maybe I need to change the values of "1" and "2"'s to maybe "yes" and "no"'s ? 
can someone guide me ?

> str(mydataR)

'data.frame':   1024 obs. of  35 variables:

$ B1   : num  252 217 244 283 147 ...

$ B2   : num  0.153 0.17 0.166 0.173 0.163 ...

$ B3   : num  0.0844 0.0918 0.0872 0.0883 0.0817 ...

$ B4   : num  0.544 0.641 0.551 0.697 0.744 ...

$ B5   : num  1.54 2.33 1.57 1.1 2.37 ...

$ Decision: int  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 ...

Comment: This is a programming related question should be moved to stackoverflow

Comment: Please ass a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536) for people to work with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: I do not know how to move a question. If you can do it without deleting my question I would appreciate it. I know some people who need this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
mydataR$Decision <- as.factor(mydataR$Decision)
```